# creating a chart using a count query on repository in symfony

Tags: symfony, highcharts, count, controller, repository

I'm working on symfony and I'm trying to count the number of employees in every team I have in my database and show them into a chart. So I created this query in the repository:

```
function findNbEmp()
{
$query = $this->getEntityManager()
    ->createQuery("Select COUNT(distinct u.id) AS nbEmp, e.nomEq as equipe
                               FROM MyAppEspritBundle:User u INNER JOIN 
MyAppEspritBundle:Equipe e
                               WITH u.id_equipe=e.idEq
                               GROUP BY u.id_equipe");

return $query->getResult();


}
```

and then went to the controller and have done this:

```
public function chartLineAction()
{

   $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $nbemps = $em->getRepository('MyAppEspritBundle:User')->findNbEmp();

    var_dump($nbemps);

    $tab = array();
    $categories = array();

    foreach ($nbemps as $nb) {
      //  var_dump($user['nbEmp']);
        array_push($tab,$nb['nbEmp'] );
      array_push($categories, $nb['equipe']);
    }


    // Chart
   $series = array(
        array("name" => "Nb employés", "data" => array($tab))
   );

    $ob = new Highchart();
    $ob->chart->renderTo('linechart');        //  #id du div où afficher le graphe
    $ob->title->text('Nombre d employés par équipe');
    $ob->xAxis->title(array('text' => "Equipe"));
    $ob->yAxis->title(array('text' => "Nb Employés"));
    $ob->xAxis->categories($categories);
    $ob->series($series);

    return $this->render('MyAppEspritBundle:Gerant:AccueilGerant.html.twig',
        array(
        'chart' => $ob
    ));
}
```

The problem is when I put $nb['nbEmp'] in array_push($tab, $nb['nbEmp']), the graph just goes away so when I let only ($tab, $nb), at least I can see the names of groups that I've made and tooken from the database.
BTW, everything is working fine in the bundle excepting the first array_push (because of nbEmp)

Even I've used var_dump, it showed me the result that I want to set on my graph but couldn't:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UrtHF.png)

I'm wondering, what is missing in my code so it could read nbEmp properly in the graph.
Can you guys help me? I'm open to other solutions too if they are more effective than this one I'm trying to achieve. Please, I need to know what should I put in that first array_push?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please, can anyone help me?

Comment: try changing `array_push($tab,$nb['nbEmp'] );` to `array_push($tab,intval($nb['nbEmp']) );`

Comment: Yes, it worked for the first array_push, thanks

Comment: good , if you find that I answered your question you may accept it

Comment: I guess you should put it as an answer so I can accept it; I didn't know how to accept it like a comment. Or you may explain to me, I'm new here too

Comment: Or, I'll vote for your previous answer; and you may edit it if you want to

Comment: ok I'll edit my answer for feature references

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function chartLineAction()
{

   $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    // $users is not the best name for this result 
    $users = $em->getRepository('MyAppEspritBundle:User')->findNbEmp();

  //  var_dump($users);

    $tab = array();
    $categories = array();

    foreach ($users as $user) {
      $tab[] = (int)$user['nbEmp']
    }


    // Chart
   $series = array(
        array("name" => "Nb employés", "data" => array($tab))
   );

    $ob = new Highchart();
    $ob->chart->renderTo('linechart');       
    $ob->title->text('Nombre d employés par équipe');
    $ob->xAxis->title(array('text' => "Equipe"));
    $ob->yAxis->title(array('text' => "Nb Employés"));
   // $ob->xAxis->categories($categories);
    $ob->series($tab);

    return $this->render('MyAppEspritBundle:Gerant:AccueilGerant.html.twig',
        array(
        'chart' => $ob
    ));
}
```

Try the code above , it should show you a result but you probably want to display 'equipe' ids ( or names )  as well with the number of employees. For that you need to modify your query like this :

```
function findNbEmp()
{
$query = $this->getEntityManager()
    ->createQuery("Select COUNT(distinct u.id) AS nbEmp, u.id_equipe as id_equipe
                               FROM MyAppEspritBundle:User u
                               GROUP BY u.id_equipe");

return $query->getResult();
}
```

and then fill your `$categories` with `$users['id_equipe']` and uncomment the line that I commented :

```
// $ob->xAxis->categories($categories);
```

Try the first part of my suggestion then if you get a chart , you will be more confortable modifying and playing with different options.

Comment: Hello zizoujab, thank you for answering me, the problem is : the code can only read nbEmp if it is in an array_push.
For this line: 
    $tab[] = (int)$users['nbEmp']

it displayed me this: Notice: Undefined index: nbEmp

Comment: And yes, I wasn't thinking about the name of the variable, I was just trying to make it work. I will change it. Thank you :)

Comment: Zied,I have also followed you remark and I've changed in my query and actually the var_dump has changed too:

    function findNbEmp()
    {
     $query = $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery("Select COUNT(distinct u.id) AS nbEmp, e.nomEq 
     as equipe
                                   FROM MyAppEspritBundle:User u INNER JOIN 
    MyAppEspritBundle:Equipe e
                                   WITH u.id_equipe=e.idEq
                                   GROUP BY u.id_equipe");

     return $query->getResult();


    }

Comment: @NouhaBalti sory it's `user` not `users` without s

Comment: Yes, I corrected it by myself, I changed categorie and now it working good, the problem is in the 'nbEmp' itself 
there is something missing either in array_push which worked for categorie or tab[]

Comment: I'm going to write an answer just to show you the changes I've made

Comment: this is for the repository:

function findNbEmp()
{
    $query = $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery("Select COUNT(distinct u.id) AS nbEmp, e.nomEq as equipe
                                   FROM MyAppEspritBundle:User u INNER JOIN MyAppEspritBundle:Equipe e
                                   WITH u.id_equipe=e.idEq
                                   GROUP BY u.id_equipe");

    return $query->getResult();


}

Comment: and this is the controller:

 public function chartLineAction()
    {

       $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $nbemps = $em->getRepository('MyAppEspritBundle:User')->findNbEmp();

        var_dump($nbemps);

        $tab = array();
        $categories = array();

        foreach ($nbemps as $nb) {
          //  var_dump($user['nbEmp']);
            array_push($tab,$nb['nbEmp'] );
          array_push($categories, $nb['equipe']);
        }

Comment: And this is how the var_dump changed:

array(4) { [0]=> array(2) { ["nbEmp"]=> string(1) "3" ["equipe"]=> string(5) "admin" } [1]=> array(2) { ["nbEmp"]=> string(1) "1" ["equipe"]=> string(17) "Ressource Humaine" } [2]=> array(2) { ["nbEmp"]=> string(1) "1" ["equipe"]=> string(13) "Comptabilité" } [3]=> array(2) { ["nbEmp"]=> string(1) "3" ["equipe"]=> string(14) "Développement" } }

Comment: you can edit your question to reflect your changes and show where you have the new problem